# Dependency injection with multiple-layered application

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm currently struggling a bit to understand how I can use the dependency injection pattern outside of my controller classes.

Say for instance that I have the following controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller {

  ILog logger;

  public TestController(ILog log) {

   logger = log;

  }

  public string TestMethod() {

    businessLayer businessLayer = new businessLayer();

    return businessLayer.DoSomethingAndLogIt();

  }

}
```

I understand that in most cases it is not possible to use constructor injection outside of the controller-classes. So it would not be possible to directly use the ILog-implementation insdie the "businesslayer"-class.

One simple solution I could imagine is the following:

```
public class TestController : Controller {

  ILog logger;

  public TestController(ILog log) {

   logger = log;

  }

  public string TestMethod() {

    businessLayer businessLayer = new businessLayer(logger);

    return businessLayer.DoSomethingAndLogIt();

  }

}
```

So passing on the dependencies from the controller to the underlaying layers. But is this the best way? Are there better solutions to have my businessLayer-class access to the ILog-implementation?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that in most cases it is not possible to use constructor
>   injection outside of the controller-classes.

This is incorrect. You should use constructor injection for all your components (every class in your application that contains behavior).

Dependency injection is about injecting dependent services/components into consuming components. So this means that you should not new up the `businesslayer` class in your controler; you should inject it using the constructor. By newing up this dependency you are violating the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), which causes high coupling. This again makes your code harder to test and makes it harder to change the controller and makes it much harder to apply cross-cutting concerns (such as logging, audit trailing, transaction management, etc) to the system.

> So it would not be possible to directly use the ILog-implementation
>   insdie the "businesslayer"-class.

Incorrect. The `ILog` implementation should be injected into the constructor of your `businesslayer` class.

Long story short, your controller should look like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller {
  IBusinessLayer businessLayer;

  public TestController(IBusinessLayer bl) {
   this.businessLayer = bl;
  }

  public string TestMethod() {
    return businessLayer.DoSomethingAndLogIt();
```

}
}

Since `TestController` doesn't seem to use `ILog` directly, it should not be injected into its constructor. `ILog` is an implementation detail of the business layer class and implementation details should not leak to the consumer (this would again be a violation of the Dependency Inversion Principle).

Comment: Thx! One thing I didn't understand was how the IBusinessLayer would use the ILog implementation. But most DI-containers seem to be able to solve this when registering. http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#automatic-constructor-injection-auto-wiring

Comment: @Matthias: This isn't about DI containers. Each class should simply accept the dependencies it (directly) needs as constructor arguments and in the startup path of the application you build up the complete object graph(s) (the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)). You don't need a DI container to do this and it can even have benefits to not use a container at all. On the other hand, a DI container can help making your Composition Root much more maintainable.